# Typescript does not see parameter validation in closure

Tags: typescript

In my code

```
interface INode {
    id: number,
    label: string;
    parentId?: number; 
}

let nodes: null | INode[] = null;

nodes = [
    { id: 0, label: 'zero' },
    { id: 1, label: 'one', parentId: 0 },
    { id: 2, label: 'two', parentId: 0 },
    { id: 3, label: 'three', parentId: 1 },
    { id: 4, label: 'four', parentId: 3 },
]


function calcBreadcrumbs(nodes: null | INode[]) {
  if (nodes === null) return;

  const id = 33

  function _findNode(nodeId: number): void {
    const node: INode | undefined = nodes.find(n => n.id === id);
    if (node === undefined) {
      throw new Error(`calcBreadcrumbs. Node ${nodeId} not found`);
    }

    // some code

    if (node.parentId) _findNode(node.parentId);

    return;
  }

  _findNode(id);
}
```

[sandbox 1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDkD2ATFBvAKGWOWGwC5kQBXAWwCNoAaIkgGzkbcoGcwpQAcwDcrYgAc4UCOFTYA-JRoNow5AQC+BAmwhgqOCDyXU2bZAB80WXAG0AusgC8VU21EEQhns+S2xyHikFMgADEzIHFyUAOQAXtCYMcgaLCSBwZQAjBFRENzIMZggEDERktKyIaEpaSRBZJQATLmc+bFgAO5J5VIyYHKUNakBDSEAzK3RhWAAFtKlvZUDIVm1o5nIACxT7YUwmNRQZcgV-YPI4+v22gQw1CAIYMDFyAhwbAgAQtJw2AhQOj0HgACi8uGMrjMlmshgcAEpAqxgDBkGDvM4nC4aGZEdIwEcQB5iAhinxgr5xuNtMR7o9nq8APowUDYGwQdG4C7KRhQeGUABumDISPSpJA5PBEEoGEMMIeuBZJWwvilPAAdErsGDnAA+KjqkVYlxkeGidIotFSzEuBUQJUQbCIwjpYhzKCYTpUCBegCiUA9UBBAAN3p8fhA-gCgRrkOzkAASPBSuQaAz6A4K4NmgJaAIAenzyB4mFoKFJuBpJEtnIg6rOVURzNZ7Nr9b6jeJJHxhPNKSrzZAbMMINNog0QA)
I check `if nodes === null`. But TS talk me 'Object is possibly 'null'.(2531)'
if you pass nodes to the _findNode function, then TS does not swear

```
function _findNode(nodes: INode[], nodeId: number): void {...}
```

[sandbox 2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDkD2ATFBvAKGWOWGwC5kQBXAWwCNoAaIkgGzkbcoGcwpQAcwDcrYgAc4UCOFTYA-JRoNow5AQC%20BAmwhgqOCDyXU2bZAB80WXAG0AusgC8VU21EEQhns%20S2xyHikFMgADEzIHFyUAOQAXtCYMcgaLCSBwZQAjBFRENzIMZggEDERktKyIaEpaSRBZJQATLmc%20bFgAO5J5VIyYHKUNakBDSEAzK3RhWAAFtKlvZUDIVm1o5nIACxT7YUwmNRQZcgV-YPI4%20v22gQw1CAIYMDFyAhwbAgAQtJw2AhQOj0HgACi8uGMrjMlmshgcAEpAqxgDBkGDvM4nC4aGZEdIwEcQB5iAhinxgr5xuNtMR7o9nq8APowUDYGwQdEQygYOH2CLgiAXZSMKDwygAN0wZCR6VJIHJAu57JhD1wLJK2F8Ap4ADp1dgwc4AHxUHXSrEuMjw0TpFFogWYlyqiDqiDYRGEdLEOZQTCdKgQf0AUSgvqgIIABu9Pj8IH8AUDdchlQASPACuQaAz6A6qiPWgJaAIAemLyB4mFoKFJuBpJDtnIgOrOVURzNZ7MbPH5hmbfVbxJI%20MJNpSdfbIDZhi7EStog0QA)
Why is it so? How to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

That's because in the first example the type of `nodes` for the inner function is still `null | INode[]` and it potentially can be `null`. For example it can be set to `null` just before the call to `_findNode(id);`

One of the possible solutions would be assigning the parameter to another variable:

```
function calcBreadcrumbs(nodes: null | INode[]) {
  if (nodes === null) return;

  const guardedNodes = nodes; // guardedNodes is INode[]
  const id = 33

  function _findNode(nodeId: number): void {
    const node: INode | undefined = guardedNodes.find(n => n.id === id);
    // ...

    return;
  }

  _findNode(id);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDkD2ATFBvAKGWWGwC5kQBXAWwCNoAaI5AGzgdYoGcwpQA5gG4WABzhQI4VNgD8FavWgiAvgQKsIYSjgjcFVVq2QAfNFlwBtALrIAvJUOsRBELu73kllnhLlkAAyMbBwQXMgA5ABe0JgRyCrMxL6kFACMweycFBGYIBARweKS0v4BCUnIKf4ATJmh4RFgAO5xRRJSYDIU5Yk+fhQAzPXZkWAAFpIF7SVd-mkV-anIACwjYTkwmFRQhcjFnd3Ig4vW6gQwVCAIYMB5yAhwrAgAQpJw2AhQtHTcABRuXD6RxGUzmXQ2ACUVRYwBgyAB7nsdgc1CM0MkYB2IBcxAQeV4yAEVAkuGwFj0nkBehEeIJ2lInkGg3UxEu11u9wA+jBQOTdIjcEdFAwoJCKAA3TCMwjEOkgQnUigYXRgq64Xn5bCeYmkiD8oEAOk12AB9gAfJRDYyUQ5SJDaXK4QjqciHOqIJr9dDZXLiBMoJhmpQIMGAKJQQNQP4AA0ezzeEA+Xx+3ENyApyAAJHhqTIVDptFt1TGHSxiGpy8gAPTV5DcTA0FD43Csp3wwUQQ0HUrQnl8imd7sdXu4uWY7GOyvEfsgA0QP721RAA)

---

Another option would be using [non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator):

```
function calcBreadcrumbs(nodes: null | INode[]) {
  if (nodes === null) return;

  const id = 33

  function _findNode(nodeId: number): void {
    const node: INode | undefined = nodes!.find(n => n.id === id);
    // ...

    return;
  }

  _findNode(id);
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIDkD2ATFBvAKGWWGwC5kQBXAWwCNoAaI5AGzgdYoGcwpQA5gG4WABzhQI4VNgD8FavWgiAvgQKsIYSjgjcFVVq2QAfNFlwBtALrIAvJUOsRBELu73kllnhLlkAAyMbBwQXMgA5ABe0JgRyCrMxL6kFACMweycFBGYIBARweKS0v4BCUnIKf4ATJmh4RFgAO5xRRJSYDIU5Yk%20fhQAzPXZkWAAFpIF7SVd-mkV-anIACwjYTkwmFRQhcjFnd3Ig4vW6gQwVCAIYMB5yAhwrAgAQpJw2AhQtHTcABRuXD6RxGUzmXQ2ACUVRYwBgyAB7nsdgc1CM0MkYB2IBcxAQeV4fk8g0G6mIl2ut3uAH0YKBsBYIIjcEdFAwoJCKAA3TCkGHEPEE7SAiAUDC6MFXXB0-LYTwi7gAQgAdDLsAD7AA%20SjKvkohykSEiAUkeHMlD65BSiAyiDYaGEE3ECZQTDNSgQd0AUSgrqgfwABo9nm8IB8vj9uMrkIzkAASPAimQqHTaLZSgNGljENTZ5AAenzyG4mBoKHxuDJArhCJFyoOpWhtPpjPN9Y6jdxAsx2ONCSrzZADN0f0NqiAA)

The operation `x!` produces a value of the type of `x` with `null` and `undefined` excluded. Use this only if you're absolutely sure that value is defined.

Comment: This ^. More info on why TS was designed this way here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998