# Typescript complains that react component optional prop could possibly be undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, frontend

I have a simple React component like this:

```
interface ComponentProps {
    onClick?: () => void;
}

const Component = (props: ComponentProps) => {
    if (!props.onClick) {
        return <></>;
    }

    return (
        // Typescript complains: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2722)
        <button onClick={() => props.onClick()}>  
            test
        </button>
    );
};
```

Typescript complains props.onClick could be undefined, even if after the check.

Could anyone help me to understand why props.onClick can ***still*** possibly be undefined?

Comment: You marked `onClick()` as optional, meaning it can be undefined. Try to remove the question mark after `onClick()` from your interface.

Comment: I understand it is an optional one,  removing ? make the complain disappear. But my question is why after the check if (!props.onClick) return <></>; props.onClick can still possibly be undefined

Comment: That's because you're using it in a callback. Just `<button onClick={props.onClick}> ...` instead

Comment: @AlekseyL. could u elaborate a bit more why callback cause this issue ? thanks

Comment: That's because theoretically before the callback invoked some other code can change the props and potentially assign `undefined` to `props.onClick`. Similar question https://stackoverflow.com/q/64334847/1113002 More info on control flow analysis here https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998

Comment: If you use the destructure `const Component = ({ onClick }: ComponentProps) => { ... }` syntax it should fix it because you can't reassign `onClick` when it's been destructured like that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `props` object is mutable and TypeScript assumes that it can be modified between your `!props.onClick` check and the execution of the callback.

To fix your issue, you can destructure the `props` object and use the `onClick` attribute as a scoped variable:

```
const Component = ({onClick}: ComponentProps) => {
    if (!onClick) {
        return <></>;
    }

    return (
        <button onClick={() => onClick()}>  
            test
        </button>
    );
};
```

Comment: if props mutated, let's say props.onClick changed to undefined, then it triggers re-rendering, right?
if so, the button will not be rendered anymore. I mean, no button if props.onClick is undefined, there is button if props.onClick is defined.

did I understand correctly?

Comment: @Ethan No. If the `props` object is mutated, React will not be aware of it and it will not re-render the component. In the React world, `props` objects are **never** mutated. When a component is rendered, it receives a **new** `props` object. The problem is that TypeScript doesn't know how React works internally and, even if it is never the case, it assumes that the `props` object can be mutated.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are using the [optional property operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#optional-properties) `?` into the `ComponentProps` interface definition.

I see two ways to solve this issue:

The first one is to change the optional property definition to mandatory removing the `?` optional property operator, so you don't need to validate if the `onClick` function is passed to the component.

```
interface ComponentProps {
   onClick: () => void;
}
const Component = ({onClick}) => (
   <button onClick={onClick}>
       test
   </button> 
)
```

l
The second one is to create a handler function in order to validate the optional `onClick` function.

```
inteface ComponentProps {
    onClick?: () => void;
}
const Component = ({onClick}: ComponentProps) => (
   <button onClick={() => {
       if(onClick) onClick();
   }}>  
       test
   </button>
)
```

---

Bonus.
You can use spread syntax and ternary operator together to validate optional properties passed to the React component.

```
interface ComponentProps {
   onClick?: () => void;
}
const Component = ({onClick}: ComponentProps) => (
   <button {...(onClick ? {onClick} : {})}>test</button>
)
```

Answer (score -1):

use `props.onClick?.()` instead of `props.onClick()`.

This tells typescript to call onClick() only if it is defined.

[Learn more about optional chaining here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you try

```
interface ComponentProps {
    onClick?: () => void;
}

const Component = ({ onClick = () => {}}: ComponentProps) => {


    return (
      
        <button onClick={() => props.onClick()}>  
            test
        </button>
    );
};
```

Comment: This implies a different functionality, that will always render the button.